# Async Node.js requests in Angular Universal. Server rendering stops working

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, angular-universal

I do a simple request to MySQL database in Angular Universal project with Node.js.

```
router.route('/newvideos')
          .get(function(req, res) {

            var mysql = require('mysql');

            var connection = mysql.createConnection({
              host     : 'localhost',
              user     : 'root',
              password : 'root',
              database : 'myDB',
              port: '8889'
            });

            connection.connect(function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
                throw err;
              }
            });

            connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err, rows, fields) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error executing query: " + err);
                throw err;
              }

              connection.end();

              setTimeout(function() {
                res.json(rows);
              }, 0);
         });

     })
```

I receive data, however, it doesn't appear in HTML-template. I only see:

```
<!--template bindings={}-->
```

It seems Angular Universal doesn't wait to receive data from the request to database.

If anyone knows how to fix the issue I'll appreciate the advice.
Thank you.

Comment: I think `connection.query` should be called in callback of `connection.connect`.

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do it

```
router.route('/newvideos').get(function(req, res) {
  var mysql = require('mysql');

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'myDB',
    port: '8889'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
      throw err;
    } 

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM table", function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error executing query: " + err);
        throw err;
      }
      connection.end();

      return res.json(rows);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. However it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the server rendering stops working not due to async requests. It depends on Zone.js in my case.

In this case I installed Zone.js which Angular asked as I received a warning:

```
angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
```

So I installed proper Zone.js:

```
npm install zone.js@0.6.21
```

The reason for this installing was that I have found that without it all requests to MySQL were not going. An error occurred.

After I installed proper Zone.js I was able to get data from MySQL.

**BUT!** I have found that server rendering stops working in this case. It doesn't work even if I return JSON data without connecting to database.

So I have done some testing and have found that if I do the following command:

```
npm install zone.js
```

then if I return only JSON data without connection to MySQL the server rendering works fine. However the following error occurs during connecting to database at this case:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Angular2/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:152:5)
...
```

Now depends on version of Zone.js I have either server rendering or working connection to database. Not both at one time. If anyone knows what to do I'll appreciate the help. Thank you.